# How to get squirrels out of inaccessible attic before plugging their entry hole?

Tags: pest-control, pest

I have a low pitch roof that has an attic between it and the ceiling which is low enough to be useless for storage and access.  I have had a problem with squirrels entering for a while and I finally found the hole they are using to enter.  I would like to plug the hole but would not like to leave any squirrels inside to either try to dig another way out or go crazy while waiting for inevitable and slow, awful death.

Is there any way to lure them out before I plug the hole?  They can be heard moving in the ceiling sometimes but an absence of the noise does not guarantee they are not inside.

Comment: I've seen landlords try to use mothballs to drive squirrels out of ceilings. I have no idea if it works.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the other answers that recommend a one-way pest exit door based on the comments that the current hole size and location will not accommodate such a door: You can always patch the current hole, create a new one for the door (preferably in an inconspicuous location if possible), and then either remove and patch up the new hole after you are sure all pests are gone or leave it in place should pests find a new entryway in the future.

Comment: very high level of effort but makes sense

Comment: @amphibient This is the solution with the least amount of total effort, IMO

Comment: no, the least amount of effort is to be lucky that no rodents are inside when you plug the hole for good

Comment: I'm assuming @amphibient home has soffit vents.  Just install the exit door there and plug the original hole.  After the rodents are gone, remove and replace the screen on the soffit.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the way this is handled is by installing one-way doors so that the squirrel can exit but not re-enter. They will exit throughout the day to obtain food, the exception being very young babies.   I think at this time of year it is unlikely to have young babies in there, so you are probably safe (humane?) to use the one-way door and just wait for them to all leave.

Keep in mind that some squirrels, especially red squirrels are very persistent and will try and find another way in, so unless you do a really good job sealing all the entry holes, they might just find their way back in again.  They can squeeze through amazingly small spaces.

Common entry points are corners where the roof meets the soffits, vents, turbines, etc.

Comment: the position and shape of the hole does not make this approach feasible

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the hole?

Comment: Also the "door" could be something as simple as a mesh that they can push out of the way to get out, but not push in to enter.

Comment: do you think they will go crazy before they die if they don't get out and cause damage inside the attic ?  set humane concerns aside

Comment: Yes likely they will scratch and chew their way out

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install a one way pest door at the entrance they are using.  Here is an example of one I found on amazon.  [http://www.amazon.com/Tomahawk-Excluder-One-Way-Door/dp/B00B9JVD7K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B9JVD7K)

Comment: the position and shape of the hole does not make this approach feasible

Comment: Your best option then is to talk with a local pest company on how to get rid  of them.  They will have the local knowledge of what works and doesn't.

Comment: If the hole is an irregular size, you could use some other material to "funnel" them into this square shaped device.  Screen or hardware cloth or something.  They're not going to make a trap for every sized hole.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'd trust the one-way door unless you have a clear single access point. I'd probably go with some [predator scent](http://www.predatorpeestore.com/Fox-urine-for-Squirrels-Chipmunks.html). Use it sparingly and you're unlikely to detect it inside the home.

Answer (score -1):

Play loud bassy, music. Generally the pop crap, that the teeny boppers listen to. You laugh but It works.

Comment: I bet there's a "Scare the Squirrels" mix tape available somewhere...